# Jasmine Test Observable complete function in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, jasmine

I want to test the "complete" handler of an rxjs Observable in Jasmine.

This is my code I want to test:

```
  doSomething()
  {
    const subscription = this.service.getObservable().subscribe(
        (next) => {
        //do something
        },
      (error) => {
        //handle error
      },
      () => {
        // do something on complete <== How can I test this function?

      }
    );
  }
```

I have written tests for the "next" handler by creating a spy:

```
const spy = spyOn<any>(service, 'getObservable').and.callFake(() => {
  return from(['nextValue']);
})
```

I have written tests for the "error" handler by creating a spy which throws an error:

```
const spy = spyOn<any>(service, 'getObservable').and.callFake(() => {
  return throwError(new Error('error message'));
})
```

**Question**: How can I mock the complete handler?

Comment: Is onComplete method trigger when we got success response from `service.getObservable()`. Correct me If I am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can mock the complete handler with jasmine:

```
const spy = spyOn<any>(service, 'getObservable').and.callFake(() => {
      return new Observable(subscriber => {
        subscriber.complete();
      });
    });
```